# Como puedo hacer funcionar codigo originalmente de js a C#

Tags: javascript, c#

Quisiera ayuda en un ejercicio de aventura JS para c#. El ejercicio es este:

Crear una función que permita agrupar un arreglo, que puede ser de valores u objetos, a través de una función o una propiedad.

EJ:
*groupBy([6.1, 4.2, 6.3], Math.floor) // { 6: [6.1, 6.3], 4: [4.2] }*

*groupBy(['uno', 'dos', 'tres'], 'length') // { 3: ['uno', 'dos'], 5: ['tres'] }*

*groupBy([{edad: 23}, {edad: 24}], 'age') // { 23: [{edad: 23}], 24: [{edad: 24}] }*

En js se vería así, pero lo necesito para C#

```
export default function groupBy(collection, it) {
  let obj = {};
  for(let ele of collection){
    if(obj[ (typeof it === 'function') ? it(ele) : ele[it] ] === undefined){
      obj[ (typeof it === 'function') ? it(ele) : ele[it] ] = [];
    }
    obj[ (typeof it === 'function') ? it(ele) : ele[it] ].push(ele);
  }
  return obj;
}
```

¿podría ayudarme a verificar para que funcione en c #, por favor?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podemos ayudarte una vez que lo traduzcas, a resolver algun problema en particular.. pero no vamos a hacerlo por ti...

Comment: Si supiera o tuviera claro como hacerlo en C# no estaria preguntando...

Comment: es que.. no estas preguntando.. estas pidiendo que lo hagan por vos ;)

Comment: Bueno entonces como puedo hacer esto (typeof it === 'function') en C#

Comment: Para mi, vas a necesitar una funcion polimorfica, que sepa de antemano si lo que recibe es una funcion, o una cadena que simboliza una propiedad.

Comment: Con una búsqueda podrías haber encontrado la función de Linq con el mismo nombre, [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby).

Comment: Hola amigo he visto que has creado otra pregunta muy similar a esta: [¿Cómo puedo realizar una comparación...](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/581310/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-realizar-una-comparaci%c3%b3n-para-determinar-si-un-par%c3%a1metro-es-una-func) lo recomendable si crees que una pregunta esta asociada a la otra o tienen un nuevo escenario utiliza la misma publicacion; editala y agrega una seccion de update, de tal manera que los usuarios que te estan ayudando pueda ver con mayor claridad tus dudas.

Comment: a menos que un moderador o los mismo usuarios de la comunidad no te lo pidan, tu otra pregunta corre el riesgo de ser cerrada como duplicado.

Comment: eh realizado una edicion de tu preguntya para que encaje en el sitio y solicitado la re-apertura, creo que tu preguna es valida, pero te aconsejaria escuchar a los que te comentan ... son quienes te pueden ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas preguntar si es una función, C# es fuertemente tipado, es decir si el argumento de una función es otra función tiene que ser así.

Si necesitas que una función reciba como argumento otra función y un string, puedes aprovechar la `sobrecarga` y crear 2 funciones con el mismo nombre, pero con argumentos distintos

Sobre el retorno de la función, lo que tienes se parece mucho a un `Dictionary` que tiene dentro una lista, por lo que creo sería el mejor tipo de retorno para tu caso

La función te quedaría así, creo que es la misma lógica que tienes en tu javascript. Es decir se va evaluando la función y se inserta en un diccionario. Si no existe la clave la crea

```
public static Dictionary<E,List<T>> GroupBy<T,E>(IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T,E> it)
{
    Dictionary<E, List<T>> result = new();

    foreach(var ele in collection)
    {
        var e = it.Invoke(ele);
        if (!result.ContainsKey(e))
            result.Add(e, new List<T>());

        result[e].Add(ele);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Y con algo re `reflection` se puede crear una sobre carga de esta manera, para que el argumento sea un `string`, pero OJO!!! que en este caso solo estoy evaluando propiedades del objeto, depende de ti agregar más funcionalidad

Acá ya es distinto a tu código, se pregunta por el tipo de objeto y se evalúa la propiedad de él. Como esta evaluación es una función, se vuelve a llamar a la función principal

```
public static Dictionary<E,List<T>> GroupBy<T, E>(IEnumerable<T> collection, string it)
{
    Type tpo = typeof(T);
    var prop = tpo.GetProperty(it);
    return GroupBy(collection, a => (E)prop.GetValue(a));
}
```

Código completo, incluye las 2 formas (argumento como función y como string), excepto en el primer caso, ya que la función `Math.Floor` no es una propiedad de los decimal.

Cabe señalar, para invocar la función cuando el argumento es un `string` es necesario declarar los tipos involucrados, ya que el compilador no es capaz de inferirlos como en el otro caso

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        decimal[] t1 = { 6.1m, 4.2m, 6.2m };
        var r1_1 = GroupBy(t1, Math.Floor);

        string[] t2 = { "uno", "dos", "tres", "cinco", "ocho" };
        var r2_1 = GroupBy(t2, a=>a.Length);
        var r2_2 = GroupBy<string, int>(t2, "Length");

        Edad[] t3 = { new Edad(23), new Edad(24) };
        var r3_1 = GroupBy(t3, a => a.edad);
        var r3_2 = GroupBy<Edad,int>(t3, "edad");

    Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(r1_1)); //{"6":[6.1,6.2],"4":[4.2]}
    Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(r2_1)); //{"3":["uno","dos"],"4":["tres","ocho"],"5":["cinco"]}
    Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(r2_2)); //{"3":["uno","dos"],"4":["tres","ocho"],"5":["cinco"]}
    Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(r3_1)); //{"23":[{"edad":23}],"24":[{"edad":24}]}
    Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(r3_2)); //{"23":[{"edad":23}],"24":[{"edad":24}]}

    }

    public static Dictionary<E, List<T>> GroupBy<T, E>(IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, E> it)
    {
        Dictionary<E, List<T>> result = new();

        foreach (var ele in collection)
        {
            var e = it.Invoke(ele);
            if (!result.ContainsKey(e))
                result.Add(e, new List<T>());

            result[e].Add(ele);
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static Dictionary<E,List<T>> GroupBy<T, E>(IEnumerable<T> collection, string it)
    {
        Type tpo = typeof(T);
        var prop = tpo.GetProperty(it);
        return GroupBy(collection, a => (E)prop.GetValue(a));
    }

}
public class Edad
{
    public int edad { get; set; }
    public Edad(int edad) => this.edad = edad;
    public override string ToString() => edad.ToString();
}
```