# C# - Como puedo hacer una comparación absoluta para ver si un parametro es una funcion

Tags: javascript, c#

Tengo un ejercicio resuelto en JS pero quiero pasarlo a C#

```
export default function groupBy(collection, it) {
  let obj = {};
  for(let ele of collection){
    if(obj[ (typeof it === 'function') ? it(ele) : ele[it] ] === undefined){
      obj[ (typeof it === 'function') ? it(ele) : ele[it] ] = [];
    }
    obj[ (typeof it === 'function') ? it(ele) : ele[it] ].push(ele);
  }
  return obj;
}
```

tengo claro como hacerlo hasta cierto punto, pero no tengo claro como hacer la validación del if (typeof x === 'function') pues en C# no es tan sencillo como en JS.

Comment: ok. no repitas la pregunta, bastaba con que editaras la anterior, porque basicamente, es a lo que llegamos en los comentarios...

Comment: Sabes usar linq? Creo que por allí va tu solución

Comment: he usado linq muy poco, estaba mirando algo de GroupBy, pero no sé si eso me funciona.

Answer (score 0):

C# es fuertemente tipado, para llegar a tu caso se me ocurre 2 posibilidades

**1.- Usar Genéricos**

```
public static object GroupBy<T>(T it)
```

Donde T es un genérico, es decir puede ser cualquier cosa

**2.- El argumento es de tipo "Object"**

```
public static object GroupBy(Object it)
```

Además hay que señalar que para que una función pueda recicbir como argumento otra función se deben ocupar [delegados](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-func-delegate) `Delegate`, que técnicamente es un puntero a una función, con esto claro ahora sabemos que lo que tenemos que buscar es un `Delegate`, es decir

```
if(it is Delegate)
```

Ejemplo:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    
    Console.WriteLine(groupBy(funcion_de_ejemplo_1)); //es función
    Console.WriteLine(groupBy(funcion_de_ejemplo_2)); //es función
    Console.WriteLine(groupBy("soy un string")); //NO es función
    Console.WriteLine(groupBy(1));  //NO es función
    Console.WriteLine(groupBy(false));  //NO es función
}
public static void funcion_de_ejemplo_1() { }
public static int funcion_de_ejemplo_2(int a) { return 1; }
public static string groupBy(object it)
{
    if(it is Delegate)
    {
        return "es función";
    }
    return "NO es función";
}
```

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/581298/como-puedo-hacer-funcionar-codigo-originalmente-de-js-a-c ...

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Interpreté que son preguntas distintas, que usan el mismo código de ejemplo, esta pide como sabes si el argumento de una función es otra función, y la otra pregunta trata sobre traspasar un código de JS a C#

Comment: las publicaciones que tienen dos preguntas basadas en el mismo codigo y no son extensas pueden ser respondidas en un solo post, por lo tanto es duplicado de la primera. se puede corregir editando la primera pregunta y tu respuesta en la misma.

Comment: Se ve que debe tener experiencia en Javascript, pero parece que se quiso meter de lleno con C# sin aprender las bases del lenguaje ni tener experiencia en otro lenguajes de tipado fuerte. Entonces se encuentra en una situación que va desarrollando a medida que hace preguntas y le responden.